# VScode does not pretty print in the debug pane but does via the the debug console

Tags: c++, makefile, gdb, vscode-debugger

This issue happens for a C++ with Makefile on Debian Bullseye.

I can pretty print a vector (for example, `this->my_map`) via the debug console (namely, via `-exec p this->my_map`), but something doesn't click with the debug pane (on the left side of the photo).

`launch.json` does specify `-enable-pretty-printing` as `true`.

Any idea what goes wrong?

[image]